# No ad's use but playstore detect com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID

Tags: android, flutter

hello I can't publish my app because playstore detect `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID`

```
Your manifest file includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission. This means that your app claims to use an advertising ID. Select "Yes" or remove this permission from the manifest file.
```

but my manifest use only

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

I have in the passed used admob but it was 2 years I have no admob package. It can be cause of android 13 ?
How can I do to publish ?

Comment: Does a library you rely on use it?  Permissions are transitive.

Comment: I have no library who can rely with. It the first upgrade after 1 year, I juste upgrade flutter to version 3 and make all migration nullsafety but no add package and all worked good before. I don't understand why now I have this message. The only reference with admob is the google-services.json of firebase who is associated with old admob account but no used. Even when I remove the admob_app_id it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its shows this error, i have also faced this problem, simple solution is to skip this for this time, you can find skip button from Dashboard of app in google play console

Comment: I can't ignore the error :(

Comment: are you on linkdin?

Comment: I have no linkdin

Comment: share me your gmail

Comment: I have resolve the problem by tell to playstore I use ad id to make app functionnal  ^^ mais email is vlrb33@gmail.com if you have a solution

Comment: This is not a solution and this cannot be skipped.

Comment: it can be skipped